# In Angular add api to workflow

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I updated my frontend app to call the API as below sample with Angular

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For this i created API and a web app for it.

I am trying to do below operations but couldn't able to to it.

- How to add this to my workflow?
- How to configure my settings?

Comment: Have you seen this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings) to configure your app settings for Azure Static Web? This might help your bullet point #2

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps and this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=angular) to check for #1:

1. Build static webapp before adding the API.
2. Create the API (You can create Azure functions for your statics website API)
3. As you have added the frontend code in angular to get the API (Same code has been mentioned in MS Docs)
4. Run the frontend and API locally with below commands:

   ```
    npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
    npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3

    #build frontend app:
    npm run build --prod
    #start CLI
    swa start dist/angular-basic --api-location api
   ```
5. Add API to workflow with below steps:

   1. Open your workflow at  *.github/workflows/azure-static-web-apps-.yml*.
   2. Search for the property  `api_location`  and set the value to  `api`.
   3. Save the file.

For #2 you can refer to this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings)